# List index out of range when trying to read in a txt file in Python

Tags: python, list, text, iteration

I want to read a txt file in Python. The text file consists of 3 columns, all are separated by a ','. One column represents the ID, one for a random float number, and one for the assigned attribute (solo, not solo, acc).

My goal is to convert values for 'solo' and 'acc' to 'not solo', and afterwards calculate the variable y.

The user is asked to enter an ID (number) in. Then I want to convert the lines of the txt file into a list and search for the remaining values, e.g. User enters in: 45 --> I want to search for the assigned value, then convert it to 'not solo' and calculate y. In the end, I want to print the assigned value in the unit 'not solo' as well as the y-calculation.

However, when I am trying to find the values, I get an error saying that my list index would be out of range. Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

I am browsing for hours but I can't find a solution that works.

Thank you so much!

```
import math

fobj = open('test.txt', 'r')
file_content = fobj.readline()
fobj.close()

for file in file_content:

file = file.strip()
file_list = file.split(',')

ID_q = int(input("Please enter number [else enter 'finished']:"))
ID = ID_q + 1

if ID_q != "finished":
    output = "Your ID {} is assigned to following values: ".format(ID_q)
    print(output)

    #Now the fun part starts!
    chosen_line = [ID]

    for position, line in enumerate(file_content):
        if position in chosen_line:
            file_line = chosen_line.split(',')

            ID_inline = file_list[0]
            print(ID_inline)

            if file_list[2] == 'solo':
                x = float((float(file_list[1])) * (math.pi/180))
                x_result = float("not solo: {0}".format(x))
                x_result = round(x_result, 2)

                y = float(math.sin((6*(float(file_list[1])))-(3*math.cos((float(file_list[1]))))))
                function = float("f(x) = {0}".format(y))
                function = round(function, 2)

                print(x_result)
                print(function)

            elif file_list[2] == 'acc':
                x = float((float(file_list[1])) * (math.pi/200))
                x_result = float("not solo: {0}".format(x))
                x_result = round(x_result, 2)

                y = float(math.sin((6*(float(file_list[1])))-(3*math.cos(float(file_list[1])))))
                function = float("f(x) = {0}".format(y))
                function = round(function, 2)

                print(x_result)
                print(function)

            else:
                x = ID
                y = float(math.sin((6*(float(file_list[1])))-(3*math.cos(float(file_list[1])))))
                function = float("f(x) = ".format(y))
                function = round(function, 2)

                print(x)
                print(function)

else:
    print("Bye.")
```

Comment: Could you arrange your indentation?

Comment: Check your loops : may be too many and variables are difficult to follow : file_list, file_content, choosen_line

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
fobj = open('test.txt', 'r')
file_content = fobj.readline()
fobj.close()
```

You are reading only one line, not the whole file.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask: how could I read all lines as lists?

Comment: Try: 'fobj.read()'